# MySQL doesn't appear in Data Source Configuration Wizard

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010

Because I am kinda new to programming, I would like to use the Data Source Configuration Wizard in Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 to create a connection with my MySQL database.

I installed [this](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) adapter and rebooted my computer. However, when I click the New Connection button, MySQL doesn't appear.

I also checked the references, all MySQL references are on.

I hope anyone could help.

Regards,
Jelle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the steps that you took?

I don't have 2012, but I have 2010 and I'm quite sure it won't be too different. I tried to use MySQL and I can see MySQL inside my option.

My steps are as follow:

1. Choose the **SQL Database** as the **Data Source Type**
2. Select **New Connection**
3. On the **Data source** (default is Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient)) click **Change**
4. On the **Data source** list, I can see **MySQL Database**. Select it and press **OK**
5. Enter the **Server Name**, **User name**, and **Password**

Can you see above steps?

Comment: Thanks for your response!. It goes a bit different at 2010. When I add a new datasource, I have to follow a wizard. However, I recognise what you are saying. I get stuck at point number 4. MySQL database simply doesn't appear at my list.

Comment: Yes, after I try to search on the net, if you use the latest .Net connector (6.5.5) you should be able to see it, **however**, based on the [Support Site](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,546265,564533#msg-564533) "**Note on Express editions: Visual Studio Integration has never been supported in express editions, due to Microsoft legal constraints.**"

Comment: Ok. I couldn't find it anywherre. Thanks for your help, it does look like I have to use another version.